# Criar tabela verdade em C#

Tags: c#, tabela-html, lógica, combinações

Possuo uma função de testes que deve receber diferentes combinações de entrada, para definir estes padrões irei utilizar uma tabela verdade.

Porém, estou com dificuldades em gerar a tabela verdade, fiz um protótipo inicial, que funciona bem com até 11 entradas, a partir disso fica muito lento.

Fiz da seguinte forma:

Utilizando o objeto Random gero números binários para cada uma das entradas. Por exemplo: se o programa tiver 5 entradas, gero 5 números aleatórios (entre 0 e 1).

Estes números são unidos numa string para formar a combinação e então jogados numa lista (caso seja único ou já não tenha sido descoberto anteriormente). A partir do número de entradas, consigo saber o número total de combinações a serem geradas, então ao completar o total, o programa se encerra.

Porém, por ficar tentando descobrir cada combinação de forma aleatória, ao ser necessário uma tabela verdade com 20 entradas, por exemplo, (o que geraria mais de 1 milhão de combinações), o programa se torna extremamente lento para finalizar a tarefa. Pois ao final, se repetem muitas combinações que já foram criadas e a descoberta de novas combinações se torna extremamente difícil. Há outra forma mais eficiente de resolver este problema?

```
public void GerarTabela(int entradas)
    {
        double TotalDeLinhas = Math.Pow(2,Convert.ToDouble(entradas)); // Calcula o total de linhas a serem geradas;
        int[] linha = new int[entradas]; // Cada elemento da linha é jogado em uma posição do vetor
        int LinhasGeradas = 0;
        string LinhaString = ""; // Do vetor, os elementos são unidos nesta String
        List<string> linhas = new List<string>();
        Random randNum = new Random();

        while (LinhasGeradas < TotalDeLinhas) //Permanece no loop enquanto não completar todas as combinações.
        {      
            for (int i=0; i < Entradas; i++) // Gera uma combinação
            {
                   linha[i] = new int();
                   linha[i] = randNum.Next(0, 2); //Gera um num. aleatório entre 0 e 1;
            }

            for (int i=0; i < Entradas; i++) //Transforma o vetor de combinações em uma única string. (Ex: 0 - 1 - 0 - 1)
            {
                if (i == Entradas - 1) // Se for o ultimo número da combinação, não irá ter traço após ele.
                {
                    LinhaString += linha[i];
                } else
                {
                    LinhaString += linha[i] + " - ";
                }
            }

            if (!linhas.Contains(LinhaString)) // Se não tiver esta combinação na lista, adiciona ela.
            {
                linhas.Add(LinhaString);                    
                LinhasGeradas++;
            }
            LinhaString = "";                                       
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Tabela verdade gerada com sucesso!","Concluído!");           
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode colocar o código C# na sua pergunta, por favor?

Comment: Conforme solicitado, incluí o código aqui.

Comment: Esse caminho aleatório está muito esquisito. Tem alguma motivação para usá-lo?

Comment: Foi uma gambiarra, pois meu conhecimento lógico é limitado, mas já removi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode fazer o seguinte:

As combinações da tabela verdade podem ser interpretadas como um numero binário em que cada algarismo é uma variável.

Exemplo:

```
A | B
0   0 >> 0 binario
0   1 >> 1 binario
1   0 >> 2 binario
1   1 >> 3 binario
```

Assim.. voce pode gerar a sequencia de números binários e atribuir cada algarismo a cada variável que voce possui.

Para garantir que o numero tenha 5 algarismos, voce pode converter o numero para String utilizando o metodo String.PadLeft(quantidade_variaveis,"0")

E apos ter o numero binario como String.. voce atribui cada algarismo dele para cada variavel sua, assim terá todas as combinações da tabela verdade.

Exemplo de código:

```
For i As Integer = 0 to (quantidade_variaveis - 1)
  string binario = Convert.ToString(i, 2)
  binario = binario.PadLeft(quantidade_variaveis,"0")
  char[] arr = binario.toCharArray(0, binario.length)
  //variavel 1 = arr[0]
  //variavel 2 = arr[1]
  ...

End For
```

Comment: Isso resolveu a gambiarra que eu havia criado, pois agora não uso mais o Random. Porém, a velocidade para criar as tabelas maiores, por incrível que pareça, é semelhante.